# PHP reapet foreach until

Tags: php, foreach, repeater

I print img html elements by a foreach cycle.

Images are stored in db so if they are 40 foreach will print 40 img

Now i need that if they are 40 in db and i need to print 100 img elements, to repeat the cycle until they are 100, is it possible to do that?

EDIT:

to be clear, i retrieve 40 img from db, i need to print "100 OF THEM" (repeat them if they are less than 100) ... hope is clear :P

Comment: Have you tried to display the img elements inside a while loop?

Comment: @Rainsen which should be the right syntax? for now i'm just using this: <?php foreach($gen as $user){?>
 <img  src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user->fb_aliasname; ?>/picture?type=square"  alt="" >
 <?php } ?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Iterators](http://php.net/iterator):

```
$images = new LimitIterator(
    new InfiniteIterator(
        new ArrayIterator($imgArray)
    ), 
    0, 100
);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    // print images
}
```

The [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/ArrayIterator) makes your `$imgArray` iterateable by other Iterators. The [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/InfiniteIterator) will make the wrapped `ArrayIterator` start over at the beginning when it has reached the end of `$imgArray`. Finally, the [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) will limit the iteration to 100 items.

So, when you iterate over `$images`, `foreach` will go over the elements in the image array repeating them over and over until 100 elements have been printed, e.g. this will output images 1-40, then again 1-40 and finally 1-20 because 40+40+20=100.

Demo: http://codepad.org/YeDgpsVc

Comment: this should be the answer if you can show me a control, if they are 100 from db doesn't matter the loop, if they are < 100 so launch the loop ;)

Comment: @Ispuk sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you rephrase please?

Comment: your is gonna be the flagged answer, but i need to control also if they are 100 i don't need to repeat the loop if they are less than 100 from db so i need the loop to repeat them to print 100 images

Comment: @Ispuk you control this with the given limit of the LimitIterator (third argument in constructor; here 100). Because of the InfiniteIterator, the foreach will start over and over again. The LimitIterator simply controls when the iteration should stop. When there is less than 100 images, they'll start over. When there is exactly 100 images, all 100 images will be shown. When there is more than 100 images, only the first 100 images are shown.

Answer (score 4):

Repeat 100 times and use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) on the index:

```
$images = function_to_fetch_images();

for($i=0, $count = count($images); $i<100; $i++) {
  echo $images[$i % $count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but I'm guessing that you want to show 100 images, but repeat some of the images if there's less than 100. If so, you can use a `for` loop that iterates through all the images, then when you're at the last image, and there hasn't been 100 images outputted, go back to the first one.

```
for ($i = 0, $j = count($images); $i < 100; $i++)
{
    echo $images[$i % $j];
}
```

Comment: or something like $images[$i%count($images)]   //or even better count($images) outside the loop

Comment: @Ivil Brilliant suggestion. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a nested loop for this. I am assuming you meant that you wish to repeat through the elements in the image set until you've got 100 images on the screen, even if that means some images are duplicated.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100;) {
    foreach($imageSet as $image) {
        echo $image;
        $i++;
        if ($i < 100) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct. However it might be more readable to use a ``while`` loop for the outer loop.